# Sphinx query/settings similar to Like '%string%' SQL query

Tags: sphinx

I want to search for a string in Sphinx and get all documents that contains that string

Example: search for "bot" and get the documents that contain "xbot", "robot", "botanic", etc

Basically I want my search to have same effects as running a

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name LIKE '%bot%'

How can I do that?

**Note**:
I tried to use [min_infix_len](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-infix-len) but it seems that is only extends the search a little bit but not fully. So if I set conf-min-prefix-len = 2 it will match 'xbot' but not "botanic"

Comment: Note, that min_prefix_len=2, SHOULD allow "bot" to match "botanic", If it doesnt there is something else wrong. Check your workings.

Answer (score 3):

Try using wildcard in [Extended Query Syntax](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax) and min_infix_len enabled

`SELECT * FROM myindex WHERE MATCH("bot | bot* | *bot*")`

Comment: I saw that probably min_infix_len is part of the solution. I'm using SphinxQL so I might need the QL version of it (not the PHP client which seems to be deprecated). And what about 'xbot', does your query matches it?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM myindex WHERE MATCH('@* bot | bot* | *bot* /1')`

`*bot*` should match for 'xbot'

Comment: 1. I saw that the command for quorum is:     `"good fast cheap"/2` thus your command should be `SELECT * FROM myindex WHERE MATCH(' "@* bot | bot* | *bot*" /1')`.  2. Also `*bot*` makes bot* redundant, right?

Comment: No. Can't mix Quorum with 'OR' operator, can do EITHER `(bot | bot* | *bot*)` or `"bot bot* *bot*" /1`. Quorum operator with /1 is the same as plain OR. Also @* at the start is completely redundant, by default matches all fields.

Comment: @barryhunter Edited the Answer. Hope the SphinxQL is correct!